# Changing the user folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, symbolic-link

I know this could be [a duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition), but let me explain.

Let's say I want `C:\Users\Me` to be a link to `E:\me`. Like the other question says, I tried doing `mklink /d C:\Users\Me E:\me`. However, I get a "Cannot create file when that file already exists" error. Obviously, the `C:\Users\Me` folder already exists. But if I try to delete, it just comes back instantly. I tried logging off my account and logging in as the administrator, but I still get that same error.

Comment: This sounds like a lot of problems coming... I smell a reformat and reinstall eminent. ... or however you spell that...

Comment: What? Why? I just installed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove the drive specification in C:\Users\Me so that the command line instead reads:

mklink /d \Users\Me E:\me

Comment: No, that doesn't work.

Comment: FWIW, I tested that command successfully on my local system 
Do you get an error message? Dbl-check that you have admin privileges (mklink requires admin).

On second thought... try changing your first param from \Users\Me to \Users\Me2 as I think the problem is perhaps that \Users\Me already exists as a physical directory.

Comment: Note: C:\Users\Me2 should work as well - My apologies... I was incorrect in my initial post.

Comment: But if my username is "Me", why would I use the "Me2" folder?

Comment: The command you suggested, "mklink /d C:\Users\Me E:\me" will attempt to create a link named C:\User\Me that points to E:\me. Since you apparently already have a physical folder named C:\Users\Me, I was suggesting that you display/access the contents of E:\me in an alternately named folder (in this case, "me2" :)

Comment: Well, that would work, but the point is to modify the folder that Windows 7 recognizes as the user's, like "Documents and Settings" in XP.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your initial intention... If you are looking to move an entire user's profile to a different location, I don't think symbolic links are the best means of doing so. Does the following link help? 
http://joshmouch.wordpress.com/2007/04/07/change-user-profile-folder-location-in-vista/

Comment: Thanks, I guess that would work, but the steps are too complicated and error prone and I don't feel like doing that. If no one posts a new answer in a while, I'll accept yours.