# How can I make some space on drive C:?

Tags: windows-vista, disk-space

My setup from the factory (Asus eee top) is as follows:

- `C:` - 40GB - Windows Vista
- `D:` - 181GB - data

Right now there is 677MB free space on `C:`. Can I clear out some stuff? What should I clear out? I have turned off Internet Explorer 8 because it was giving me trouble, and I'm using Safari.

Answer (score 3):

Clear your temporary files, Windows does not clear these automatically and they build up. Mine is sitting at 400MB+ just now.

Try [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to remove temp files. You can also navigate to %temp% and delete them from there.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the C: drive, go to properties. Once inside there run the disk cleaner, that might help.
I usually clean around 1GB or 2 between old files and temp files, or dumps.

Another option is moving your page file to the D: drive, or moving "My documents" to the D: drive, but its a little more complex

Comment: See this post for moving your documents onto the other partition: http://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is uninstall any other applications you've got and reinstall them to the D: drive (if possible). This will stop C:\Program Files filling up, but won't stop the registry growing.

Check which applications install directory can be changed before proceeding.

Also use something like [TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/index.shtml) to see which folders are using the most space so you only move the ones taking up most space.

Answer (score 1):

I use and love [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/). It will help you visualize what is taking up all that space.

Answer (score 1):

Stuff I would do to sort this out.

Run something like Space Sniffer /
   TreeSize Pro | WindirStat etc to give
   a graphical representation detailing
   exactly where the space is being
   eaten up.

Run CCLeaner to clear up temporary
   files etc

Move your swapfile / page file to the
   D Drive, which will (depending on
   size) give 1gb or 2 back.

Realise that your "My Documents" / Users / Documents folders are all most likely on the C Drive. These will probably have a lot of your pictures / docus / music ni them so they could be moved.

If you have games or apps installed, check to see how much space they are using. Something like WOW will update itself but leave the updater files there. You can either uninstall these programs and reinstall on the other drive, or in some cases, simply move them.

Realise that often, your internet browser does not limit its temp space. Limiting it is a good idea if you are short of space on a drive it is using.

Answer (score 0):

These would be my first steps:

1. Run System Restore to create a current Good Restore Point
2. Run [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/)

Next I would open up an elevated Command Prompt (right click Command Prompt icon and click *Run as administrator*). Check to see the size of your restore points and how much space is allocated for them by typing in the following:

```
vssadmin list shadowstorage
```

You will  see something like:

```
For volume: (C:)\\?\Volume{45a08de4-b13e-11de-8bb3-806e6f6e6963}\
Shadow Copy Storage volume: (C:)\\?\Volume{45a08de4-b13e-11de-8bb3-806e6f6e6963}\
Used Shadow Copy Storage space: 18.996 GB (4%)
Allocated Shadow Copy Storage space: 19.313 GB (4%)
Maximum Shadow Copy Storage space: 27.94 GB (6%)
```

I would then open up Disk Cleanup (Accessories folder in the Start Menu, System Tools). Click the More Options tab then in the bottom of the page click on "Clean up..." this will present you with a popup of "Are you sure you want to remove all restore points except the last one?" or something like that. Click delete as long as your system is running fine other than having problems with space and slowness.

Now I would change the amount of space used by System Restore (back to the Command Prompt).
You should use the following command:

```
vssadmin resize shadowstorage /on=[drive letter]: /For=[drive letter]: /Maxsize=[maximum size]
```

Example:

```
C:\Users\yourname>vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=c: /on=c: /maxsize=5gb
```

The result for above example will display:

```
C:\Users\yourname>vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=c: /on=c: /maxsize=5gb
vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2001-2005 Microsoft Corp.

Successfully resized the shadow copy storage association
```

What is important is that the size is large enough to retain a few restore points, say five days worth.

You may also consider checking on your pagefile.sys and hiberfil.sys sizes.  Do you use hibernation?  If not turn it off.  Is the page file size the correct size?  The same size as memory or 1.5 times the memory size?

I think this along with the other posts should get your system managed a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably really basic, but move your videos, music, pictures to data drive if they aren't there already, and download any games to data drive, and reinstalll any games that are on your C drive to your data drive. other than what the other users said you should be set