# Moving users folder on Windows 7 to another partition

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

Question based on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition/6395#6395) answer. I want to do it like that, but I'm installing Windows 7 afresh.

Can anyone provide the exact steps to follow?

Comment: Windows 7 does not provide any mechanism for you do move then entire user folder, only some folders within the user folders. So you have to install the system and then work around the issue. Use the info in the linked question, you may also find [this](http://www.starkeith.net/coredump/2009/05/18/how-to-move-your-windows-user-profile-to-another-drive/) helpful (scroll to the bit about symlinks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps provided by `totorocat` in the linked question. They should still apply for Windows 7, and it is the easiest method to have your profile reside on a separate drive (speaking from experience)

Comment: Not suitable when there are multiple users to create on my system.

Comment: @Ismail Simply create all the users you need before changing the default profile location back to it's default value. (I.e., repeat step 3 as needed for each user)