# How do I get Windows 7 to recognize a Junctioned User folder?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, hardlink, junction

I'd like to junction or hard-link my C:\Users[me]\ folder to a folder on my D: drive for space reasons. This has worked for me in the past, but after a recent reformat/reinstall of Win7 x64, Windows doesn't seem to recognize the junction, and boots me into a temporary user profile- claiming it can't find my files or something.

I've been following this guide to the letter: http://www.starkeith.net/coredump/2009/05/18/how-to-move-your-windows-user-profile-to-another-drive/

Specifically, using SafeMode and a Admin temporary user to move user directories. Since this is a new installation, moving the [me] folder around isn't much of an issue currently, since there's nothing but the Windows generated folders inside.

In Explorer, browsing to the junction does show the folder with the 'shortcut' link over it, and it links to the correct place on the D: drive.

What am I missing? Why won't Windows recognize this junction as the profile source?

Comment: I'm very interested in a clear answer here. I ran into the same problem in the comments on this thread http://superuser.com/questions/279658/can-i-move-windows-7-c-users-more-easily-using-2-installs-of-windows-7, and it seems to be quite a sticky issue sometimes. I ended up starting over and scrapping the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you reinstalled and are trying to point Windows to your old user folders, that isn't going to work.  What happens is that your username isn't the only way Windows tracks your profile. It also uses an ID number.

Best way to solve this is to leave the *User* folder alone and create your profile first.

Then move the new profile to your desire location.

Then move your data into it.