# I'm trying to conserve SSD space & want to move User Accounts to HD

Tags: windows-7, installation, ssd, user-profiles, regedit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving users folder on Windows Vista/Seven to another partition](https://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition)

I have a newly installed Windows 7 install on an SSD, and have about 17GB free before adding any users or any programs.  After trying two different procedures to make and/or move one or all User profiles (media, etc), I have had no success.  Typical error is:

> The User Profile Service service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded.

The target disk for the Users is a RAID1 array, which is available for use in Safe Mode.  Anyway, is there some combination of regedits and copies that let me create a fresh account located in the RAID1 array (F:)?  Some references that fell short of showing the way:

- http://lifehacker.com/5467758/move-the-users-directory-in-windows-7
- http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/05/how-to-change-user-profile-default-location-in-windows-7/
- http://www.maximumpc.com/article/howtos/howto_optimize_your_windows_profile_and_media_storage_ssd

Comment: See [http://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition/451944#451944](http://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition/451944#451944).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this article to move the default profile location before: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/87555-user-profile-change-default-location.html

That said, if you still run in to problems, you might consider doing what I did on my home desktop and just redirect the actual media folders themselves, i.e. Documents, Videos, etc.  [This article](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/18629-user-folders-change-default-location.html) details that process.

Answer (score 1):

I second the idea of @phoebus, as not all "Users" folders can be moved without much hacking, so better only move as little as possible.

However, I would remark that nothing forces you store your documents, images and video in the Users folder. You can choose any folder you like.

Most of the applications you might use have options for setting the default directory. One can also use the Libraries of Windows 7 to consolidate multiple folders in one library.