# How to change the default user location in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables, user-profiles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving users folder on Windows Vista/Seven to another partition](https://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition)

I have been looking around and I figured out how to change the default program files location to D:\ and I would also like to change the %userprofile% to E:. I read that you are suppoed to go in the registry and change the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList. Problem is, I tried that, then logged off and no luck. I tried restarting and still %userprofile% shows up on the C:\ drive. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was going to suggest mounting the user profile partition over `C:\Users`, Unix-like, but it requires `C:\Users` to be empty and I can't figure that part out. It might be possible to do it by using [`psexec -desi cmd`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and `mountvol` when no-one is logged in.

Comment: Also, have you changed the `ProfileImagePath` value for every SID?