# How to move Users folder in Windows 7 to another drive in order to save space in SSD main drive?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, file-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving users folder on Windows Vista/Seven to another partition](https://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition)

I've just assembled a new computer and I am using an 120GB SSD as the main drive and a regular 1TB disk to hold the files.

As I did a fresh install of Windows 7 64bits, I would like to move the Users folder to the 1TB disk in order to save space on the SSD, where I plan to have only the applications installed.

Is it a good idea, if so how can I change the location of the Users folders?

Comment: See [http://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition/451944#451944](http://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition/451944#451944).

Answer (score 10):

Its very simple.  I do this all the time.

You need to create a Directory Junction.  First copy the `C:\Users` directory to the 1 TB drive (lets say `E:\`).  Don't forget all the hidden folders and files.  Then delete the `C:\Users` directory.  Then run the command:

```
mklink c:\users E:\Users /j
```

from an Administrator command prompt.  This will create a pointer to the folder in the new location and Windows and any programs will think everything is in the same place it always was.  I do this all the time moving games out of the Program Files directory.

Comment: Is that link global for everyone?

Comment: well yes and no, yes everyone will see it (as normally users have the list attribute on local drives), no permissions are retained the origin drive has to be NTFS for this to work, not 100% sure about destination.