# What's the quickest way to move your Windows user account to another HDD partition?

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd, user

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to move Users folder in Windows 7 to another drive in order to save space in SSD main drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/262916/how-to-move-users-folder-in-windows-7-to-another-drive-in-order-to-save-space-in)

My user is placed on my SSD, which I want to move to my 500GB because my SSD is close to full.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move Users folder in Windows 7 to another drive in order to save space in SSD main drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/262916/how-to-move-users-folder-in-windows-7-to-another-drive-in-order-to-save-space-in) and [Moving users folder on Windows Vista/Seven to another partition](http://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition)

Answer (score 0):

Use a product such as Migrate Easy to copy the contents of the SSD to the hard drive. Though you could just add the hard drive and have more space while keeping everything that's already on the SSD there.