# Set "Users" to be on drive D: instead of drive C: during installation of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving users folder on Windows Vista/Seven to another partition](https://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition)

I am planning on doing a re-installation of my Windows 7 (Home Premium) computer and I would like to set it up in a way that:

1. System and "Program Files" are on drive C: partition
2. "Users" will be on drive D: partition

What I basically want to have is to set the system up into something similar to what I usually do on my Linux installations; i.e. `/` will be the root partition and `/home` will be for the users.

Is this possible?

Comment: I believe you can use RT7Lite to do this, but I cannot check right now - I will check later this evening.

Comment: check out my post which i was in the same boat the other day, my answer also tackle's some issues that the problems arises when changing registry values while data is present etc. [Windows Installation and user profile path](http://superuser.com/questions/420398/windows-installation-and-user-profile-path)

Comment: See [http://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition/451944#451944](http://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition/451944#451944).

Answer (score 3):

There IS a way to do this. Someone had already mentions that this is possible with the WAIK (Windows Automation Image Kit).  But that's a lot of work for just one install.  Here is a better solution, albeit, unsupported. Also make sure to add the symlink that he mentions at the end, for programs foolish enough to hardcode their paths.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/win7-how-do-i-move-user-folder-to-a-different/565f16a5-e5ed-43c9-8422-4f56aebb296e

I'll cut and paste the instructions also, to prevent link rot.

> When creating a clean install, using
>   the combination of an SSD system drive
>   and a conventional disk drive, as a
>   data drive, there is a way to "move"
>   the Users folder (normally, C:\Users)
>   and the hidden ProgramData folder
>   (normally C:\ProgramData) to the
>   conventional disk, or data drive,
>   using an answer file, or unattend.xml,
>   for an unattended installation, as
>   mentioned above. For an individual
>   doing a single, one-off installation,
>   trying to figure out how to create an
>   answer file for a completely
>   unattended installation, just to
>   accomplish this one small task, is
>   way, way too much trouble.  It's also
>   not necessary.
>
> It is possible, during the course of a
>   conventional, interactive installation
>   from an installation disc or USB
>   thumbdrive, to enter what is called,
>   "Audit Mode", before the Computer is
>   named or a Username created, and
>   accomplish the necessary
>   re-assignment.
>
> 1.) Do a conventional installation.  If you are using an SSD, at the point
>   in the installation process where you
>   are asked where you want to install
>   Windows, you should use Drive Options
>   to remove any partitions on the SSD,
>   before selecting the SSD as the
>   target.  Do not manually partition or
>   format the drive, prior to
>   installation.  Windows 7 will do this,
>   and must do this, because Windows
>   needs to align the logical format with
>   characteristics of the physical drive,
>   and, also, Windows wants a small
>   system partition for its own purposes.
>
> 2.) When the installation stops, waiting for you to give the computer a
>   username and a computer name, DON'T! 
>   Press Ctrl+Shift+F3, and the computer
>   will restart in . . . (wait for it!)
>   "Audit Mode"!.  Basically, Windows
>   will create a throwaway Administrator
>   account and sign you in, as this
>   throwaway Administrator.  Nothing you
>   do, with regard to this temporary user
>   will survive finalizing the
>   installation, but the computer
>   operates normally, and you can install
>   drivers and software.  Whenever the
>   computer starts in Audit mode (you are
>   allowed to restart), a GUI version of
>   Sysprep.exe will pop up, offering to
>   restart the computer in OOBE (out of
>   box experience).  OOBE is where you
>   were a moment before -- that is, where
>   you create a username and computer
>   name and the installation is
>   finalized.  Don't choose to restart in
>   OOBE until you are ready to finalize
>   the installation.
>
> 3.)   You need to know what drive letter (or folder location) is going
>   to be assigned to your Datadrive disk.
>   So, this would be the time, in audit
>   mode, to figure that out.  If you need
>   to partition or format the datadrive,
>   do it now.  On the Start Menu,
>   right-click on "Computer" and choose
>   Manage from the context menu, to get
>   to the Computer Management console. 
>   In the Computer Management console,
>   under Storage/Disk Management, you
>   will find the tools to change drive
>   letters, partition, etc.
>
> 4.)  You need only a minimal answer file.  This is an xml file (a text
>   file), created in the Windows System
>   Image Manager application.  You can
>   call it whatever you like.  I'd
>   suggest: folders.xml.  Here's the
>   content of a folders.xml file, which
>   will re-locate Users and ProgramData
>   to D:\  
>       
>           
>               
>                   d:\Users
>                   d:\ProgramData
>               
>           
>       
>         I am going to imagine a
>   scenario, where you make this file on
>   another computer, and transfer it to
>   the computer, where the installation
>   is being done, using a USB flashdrive,
>   which, when plugged in, to the
>   computer in Audit Mode, is assigned
>   the driveletter U:  You could probably
>   just copy the text above into notepad
>   and save it as a textfile with the
>   extension, .xml and be good to go,
>   provided you wanted to use d:\Users
>   and d:\ProgramData as your Datadrive
>   locations.  (I've used this answer
>   file, successfully; I don't guarantee
>   that it will work for others.)
>
> 5. To use the folders.xml, located in the root directory of your USB
>      flashdrive, plugged in and visible as
>      U:\, you need to open a command
>      prompt, navigate to
>      c:\windows\system32\sysprep and give
>      this command: sysprep.exe /audit
>      /reboot /unattend:U:\folders.xml This
>      will cause the computer to reboot, but
>      you will end up right back in Audit
>      Mode.  As long as you are still in
>      Audit Mode, the re-location of these
>      folders will not be complete, because
>      the temporary Administrator
>      useraccount still has its stuff in
>      C:\Users and there are still some
>      active databases in C:\ProgramData.
>
> 6.) Now, you need to say goodbye to Audit Mode.  Remember that a GUI for
>   using Sysprep to initialize the OOBE
>   shows up, each time you re-boot into
>   Audit Mode.  So after you reboot in
>   5.) you will have your chance to run it.  (If this is your personal
>   computer, don't check the "Generalize"
>   box in the Sysprep GUI.)
>
> 7.) Finish your Windows installation, create a permanent username and giving
>   the computer a name, etc.  When you
>   are finally up and running, go look at
>   C:\  C:\Users should be gone. 
>   C:\ProgramData is probably still
>   there, but it's normally hidden, so
>   you won't see it, until you go into
>   Folder Options and check Show Hidden
>   Files and Folders.  D:\Users and
>   D:\ProgramData (hidden) should also
>   exist.
>
> 8.) I like the idea of using Junctions to intercept any program foolish
>   enough to hardcode to c:\users or
>   c:\programdata  You'll need to delete
>   or move C:\ProgramData, before
>   creating a Junction at C:\ProgramData
>   pointing to D:\ProgramData.  The
>   command line tool, mklink, is useful
>   here.  Open a command prompt, and type
>   mklink /? for instructions.  If you
>   prefer a right-click GUI tool, check
>   out:http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html
>   After having created the Junctions, I
>   believe you could use regedit to edit
>   the ProfileList key back to the
>   original C:\ locations.  folders.xml
>   will have modified the Folderlist key,
>   so that everything points to D:\
>   instead of %systemdrive%\ or C:\   I'm
>   not sure what the point would be, but
>   you could.
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't change the way Windows installs - but you can move the `Users` directory afterwards.

How to do that has been explained very well on Serverfault:

> [Serverfault: What's the best way to move c:\users to d:\users under vista/W7](https://serverfault.com/questions/8187/whats-the-best-way-to-move-c-users-to-d-users-under-vista-w7)

Comment: You could PROBABLY do this with WAIK in some fashion, but it would be incredibly ugly and not worth your time.  Just move it after the fact.  (Personally, I don't think there's any good reason to move it - if you want to just put the user document directories elsewhere Windows 7 already supports moving them natively whenever and whereever you want, no black magic required.  This is the second answer on the linked question.)

Comment: But that has to be done for each user and the "user document directory" is only a small part of the user profile directory. No Desktop, no AppData, no Temp,...

Comment: You're exactly right...but as I said, I don't see a compelling reason to move that stuff.  Your mileage may vary, of course.