# permanently move the c:\Users folder to another partition in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving users folder on Windows Vista/Seven to another partition](https://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition)

I have a small fast install of windows 7 on an SSD drive. I would like to move the c:\Users folder to another partition

I managed to change the HOMEDRIVE variable to be a different drive using lusrmgr.msc but the profile is still pointing to the c: partition.

I've tried using set on the USERPROFILE and HOME variables but they get reverted, and the same if I go through the environment variable GUI. The paths can be observed in the registry under HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1016127744-722935219-571307391-1000\Volatile Environment

There are a couple of related questions here, but they aren't fully answered or don't really refer to my requirements exactly. This is an existing intsall, whereby I need to move the Users folder off C to another partition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full write up for this can be found on [Life Hacker](http://lifehacker.com/5467758/move-the-users-directory-in-windows-7). Basically, you can get the desired results by moving the folder and creating a symlink.

Use your install CD, or you preferred method to get to the recovery console. Firgure our which drive is you SSD and which is your HDD, in this case SSD is E and HDD is D.

Use Robocopy to copy the user directory from the SSD to HDD:

```
robocopy /copyall /mir /xj E:\Users D:\Users
```

Remove the users directory on the SSD:

```
rmdir /S /Q E:\Users
```

Make a symlink between the old and new location:

```
mklink /J E:\Users D:\Users
```

Test by running dir in the root on your SSD, you should see something similar to "*Users [D:\Users]*"

Comment: God robocopy is slooooooooooow!!

Comment: It doesn't help anything that it is moving all of your profiles (if there is more than one) which by default contain all their documents, downloads, videos and pictures (assuming they have been saved into the default locations.) For a lot of people the "Users" folder is the largest use of space on their HDD, unless you have a lot of programs installed into Program Files but that is another story.

Comment: In my case it was only about 1.2Gb as I had already saved most bulk media on a different drive. There must some other problem, perhaps not having good drivers in the Win7 Recovery disc I was using. It would pause for ages then flick through a batch of files then pause for another age ad nauseam