# Windows 8 Media Center Pack Install Fails with DoTransmogrify failed due to error 0x80070011

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-center

When I attempt to use Add Features to install the Windows 8 Media Center pack I get the "Something Went Wrong" Message

Checking `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Anytime Upgrade\Upgrade.log` I can see the following error block

```
2012-10-27 18:43:13, Error                 WAU    DoTransmogrify failed due to error 0x80070011.
2012-10-27 18:43:13, Error                 WAU    UpgradeSKU failed. Exiting.
2012-10-27 18:43:13, Error                 WAU    The worker process exited unexpectedly
2012-10-27 18:43:13, Error                 WAU    Something went wrong
2012-10-27 18:43:13, Error                 WAU    Close this wizard and try again.
```

My understanding is that 0x80070011 means Error_Not_Same_Device. I think this may be related to the fact that `C:\Users` is a junction point to `D:\Users`

Do I have to move my users directory back? Is there a workaround?

Comment: This is due to the fact that some files in the default user profile are supposed to be hardlinked to originals in `winsxs`. No idea how you managed to move it.

Comment: @kinokijuf I [did this](http://superuser.com/q/312048/42881)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I did this on Windows 7 the extremely big updates like service packs don't support Junction Points; so yes, you'll need to move the directories back. You could attempt to temporarily mimic a folder (where the junction point now is) that only contains the Microsoft related directories, don't forget the hidden folders and system files. This last method is handy if you don't have enough space to put everything back, or when want to spare you out some time if the folders are way too large.

Comment: Well I ended up robocopying the folder over. I'll consider the Partial Move if the directories ever get too big

Answer (score 0):

The error 0x80070011 translates to "[The system cannot move the file to a
different disk drive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms837428.aspx)".

So yes, you'll need to move it back to C:\

Answer (score 0):

If using junction points to move your "Users" folder, Update the paths to their absolute locations in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Currentversion\ProfileList`.

Comment: Well it sort of defeats the purpose of using junction points but I can see it as being a viable solution. Have you tried this yourself?