# How to move the users profile entirely to another folder/partition?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

Googling resulted in copying the users folder to my desired destination while being in safe mode, and then making a junction to there from the original users fodler.
Do you know another way? maybe more intuitive one?

Comment: As far as I know the only "simple" possibility is to move each ssubfolder manually, but you will not be able to move the complete user directory any more. Researched on this a while ago, too. Maybe you could also mount the other partition as user folder?

Answer (score 2):

That is the only way to do it.

Windows needs the folder to exist, at least logically, in the C:\Users\ directory and there are enough connections to that location that you cannot usually complete the move while logged into a full windows environment without causing some problems.

So you must move the folder while in safe mode or using a Live environment and create the junction (pointer file) that points to the new location so that once you load up the full environment again the computer will find all the information where it expects it to be.

Comment: more info please :-) I heard of users loosing boot or log or something when they they messed up the users folder. Is it now a critical item, or did they screw up something else (like thier junction) ?  They put the fear in me :-)

Comment: There are always chances that the process will fail. Others have already asked the question of how to go about doing this and so I will not add that to my answer here. Please see the related questions on the right: http://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition

Comment: Thanks Music, Due to the lack of information, it prompted me to test this stuff on a hunch.  I deleted all the MY junk specific, and all the folders in library across the board, and nothing blew-up. I am assuming at this point that it is the appdata and desktop and other actually critical items, or messing up junctions that causes a fail conditition.