# Moving User folders from C drive to a new E drive then reinstall Windows 7 on the C drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, users

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I can't find one that addresses the Win7 reinstall. Also, I am not too tech savvy.

There are five users (Me, wife and 3 sons) The PC is about 4yrs old and is an i7 processor. The original HD ws 500gig, but is now almost full. I've installed and activated a 1Tb drive which shows as drive E.

I started moving my user folders, following guides from this site, using the Location tab via the folder properties. Not all folders have a Location tab and I can't move the other users even though I have an administrators account.

Also, if I reinstall Windows on the C drive will I lose all the links to the new user folder locations?

Comment: Can you link to the guides that you are using, so we know exactly what you are doing? Also, unrelated to the question, why are you reinstalling Windows 7? Is it just because the HDD is full? If so, there are other options.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to link to previous questions I have read through, I can understand why they should be credited though and I should have realised this would be a protocol- very sorry! I thought reinstalling Windows 7 would speed up my PC. It has not been touched since I bought it,

Comment: Its ok. Its not really protocol, but a way for us to see what exactly you are doing and where you might be getting stuck. All you have to do is find the guide and post the URL in either the post or a comment.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't get this to work. Initially it would get part way through copying a user folder over then say I needed an Administrator to move certain files. I enabled the elevated administrator account and tried again. It gets so far then says I need an Administrator to move the folder Feeds-United Kingdom. My only option is to skip, it then finishes and when I open the user folder on the E drive it only contains some Dat files from a game called Runescape (I was experimenting on my son's user folder)

Comment: Having done a bit more reading I think I'll go back to the Location tab method.

Answer (score 1):

Many folders cannot easily be moved without special measures.  [Some advice](https://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition) is to simply copy the entire user profile to the other drive and then create a junction link to it so that the entire folder is moved, junk and all.

```
mklink /d C:\Users\UserFolder E:\UserFolder
```

You would copy the entire profile folder over for each user, then delete (or, for safety rename it temporarily) the folder from C:\Users before running the above command.  You will have to do this as an administrator user who is not one of the users you are moving at the time, as that profile will be locked.

If you were to reinstall Windows you would first need to create all the users, log into them each individually, then recopy the profile over (so that the registry for each user is set up as new) and then recreate the links to the profile directories.

Your question regarding the folders that you can easily move such as `My Documents` and so on is an easy one, though.

When you reinstall Windows you *will* loose the link to the location that you have put the folders in, as the Windows installer will not know where the folders should be, but it is as simple as following the same procedure to move the folder as you have already done.  Right click the folder, go to Properties, then on the Location tab click "Move".

You then browse to the location you have already set up and when you click okay it will tell you that the folder is not empty.  At this point just click "OK" and it will copy whatever new files were in the *current* location to the *new* location. I have done this before with Windows 7 without problems.

Sadly though this does mean doing this for every folder for each user.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I understand this. I'll reset documents I have already moved back to the C drive.Then copy all 5 users, as described above, to the E drive and then create the 5 links.

Comment: @IanLakey I've modified the mklink command to ensure that it creates a directory link (which it should do automatically, but specified for safety) and added some info for if you needed to reinstall Windows and reuse the linked directories.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't get this to work. Initially it would get part way through copying a user folder over then say I needed an Administrator to move certain files. I enabled the elevated administrator account and tried again. It gets so far then says I need an Administrator to move the folder Feeds-United Kingdom. My only option is to skip, it then finishes and when I open the user folder on the E drive it only contains some Dat files from a game called Runescape (I was experimenting on my son's user folder)

Comment: I've been doing some more research and have decided to go back to the Location tab folder method as recommended in this article. http://www.zdnet.com/article/dont-move-your-windows-user-profiles-folder-to-another-drive/ This article also recommends not using methods suggested by 3rd party websites! I don't agree with this mind you. However, I don't think I have the IT vocabulary and knowledge to follow instructions on this site. My fault not yours. Many thanks for all of your help, time and effort. Much appreciated.

Comment: @IanLakey I personally currently use the location tab method you are following as well so don't worry about me taking offense.  Linking the entire profile directory has some other implications with regard to future upgrades and simply moving the folder contents using Windows built in features is the most future-safe imo.  I spoke about both methods because I know people have used both and it really depends how much you want to move vs level of difficulty and potential issues.

Comment: Thanks, Mokubai. I really do need to move the user folders on to the new drive. Or, put windows on the new drive! The original drive is 500gig and about 7/8 full. I take a lot of HD wildlife pictures and HD skiing videos. One of my sons edits HD pictures, so we are data heavy! Which way would you suggest I go?